# Second chance manga where a man is regressed back in time in a cultivation world

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, cultivation

I’m looking for a manga (a webcomic?) where the guy gets a second chance. He isn’t reincarnated but rather 'regresses' back in time with his memory intact.

He has a pet named Snowball.

The world is martial but there's also cultivation happening.

Comment: Hi mangaguy, welcome. You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: So a few more question do you think he is regressor(back to the past) or returner(still the same like first one but go somewhere and return Time doesn't change when he go out)? Did the pet name correctly since it is the most valuable info? The manga is about VR game or martial world or normal city love story, ....?

Comment: He’s a regressor the pet name is correct and it’s in the martial world there is cultivation in there as well but they don’t have a tag for it

Comment: Can't officially answer because the question has been closed but you are looking for "The Hunter".

Comment: @Karaelfte - It's open again now. Go for it!

Comment: It’s was the hunter thank you i appreciate it

Comment: Thanks for the reopening and you're welcome @Mangaguy

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [*The Hunter*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53423786-the-hunter) by Big Bear and Nie Bei

> Chen BeiMing was once a young and talented hunter of the Heavenly Alliance, until he got betrayed and murdered by The Five Lords. He gets resurrected into the past while having his memory intact and swears that he will get revenge on those who betrayed him. With the help of his battle sprite, he once ascends the road to become the strongest again…

**He has a pet named Snowball.**
[image: Snowball]

Found by searching for `manga hunter martial arts snowball` I also read it so I knew I needed the keyword `hunter` because unlike most cultivation stories, this one call those who practice martial arts Hunters and not Cultivators.