# What happened to Chen Beiming's parents?

Tags: manga, the-hunter

In the Korean manga *[The Hunter](https://novels-xianxiaxuanhuan.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hunter_(TH))*, what happened to Chen Beiming's parents?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Any links to show us what you're talking about?  The more research you show, the easier it will be to help.

Comment: Given the premise of the manga is that he goes back in time, it seems likely that they do not exist yet.

Comment: Note:  I found [this page](https://mangatx.com/manga/the-hunter/) which appears to match (the main character has the same name) and has English translations (albeit clunky).  The site claims to only post legal material and isn't trying to fill my browser with malware/malvertising.

Comment: FWIW, this manga was identified at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237699/second-chance-manga-where-a-man-is-regressed-back-in-time-in-a-cultivation-world although I don't think that helps here.